# Jenkins declearative Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, devops

I want to write a script that does the following
Pull a repository from git, if repository already exists means running it second then remove the old folder and pull the repository
then my repository contain docker-compose file, if docker compose already working then stop it, now docker-compose up -d 
Same code below:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Pull the repo') {
         steps {
            sh "sudo rm -r devops1"
            sh "git clone https://github.com/xyz/devops1.git"
         }
      }
      stage('run it :D'){
          steps{
              dir('devops1'){
                  sh "sudo docker-compose down"
                  sh "sudo docker-compose up -d"
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

it fails when repo is not already fetched, i'm unable to place if else condition. Looking for any help or suggestion, Thank you :)

Comment: Which part of the pipeline do you want help with? Which parts have you already tested?

Comment: i need help of all code.

Comment: pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Pull the repo') {
         steps {
            sh "sudo rm -r devops1"
            sh "git clone https://github.com/xyz/devops1.git"
         }
      }
      stage('run it :D'){
          steps{
              dir('devops1'){
                  sh "sudo docker-compose down"
                  sh "sudo docker-compose up -d"
              }
          }
      }
   }
}

Comment: check the above comment, suppose if you are running this script second time  and you remove the command sh "sudo rm -r devops1"  then it won't let you pull the repo, it will say devops1 already exists, or If it is going to be execute first then it will raise exception that devops1 not exits while removing. i'm looking to automate it. if directory exits then remove but always pull the repo, if docker-compose up already working then docker-compose down then always docker-compose up -d

Comment: rm -rf ignores nonexistent directories

Comment: docker-compose up restarts the service, no need to call docker-compose down first

Comment: docker-compose up -d ...  if you container already working in background and you again type command docker-compose up -d, then it will give me error.. like of ports, or already running etc etc

Comment: Post your answer, I want to mark it as accepted solution, your above command and instructions worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm -rf` ignores nonexistent directories

`docker-compose up` restarts the service, no need to call docker-compose down first